# How to convert dataweave code from 1.0 to 2.0

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I am not able to completely migrate the below dw 1.0 code to 2.0 version. I have pasted the partial 2.0 dw converted code below. How can I convert the rest of the code. Also please if there any tool through which I can easily convert dw 1.0 to 2.0

```html
dw 1.0

%output application/json
%var keyToMask =p('mask.key') splitBy ','

%function mask(val) "******"

%function needsMasking(key) (sizeOf (keyToMask find key)) > 0

%function maskSensitiveData(value) value mapObject ({
 ($$) : maskSensitiveData($) when $ is :object otherwise $
} unless needsMasking($$ as :string) otherwise {
  ($$) : mask($)
})

---

maskSensitiveData(flowVars.originalPayload)]]>




%dw 2.0
output application/xml encoding = 'utf-8'
ns ns0 http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
ns ns1 http://ejb.interfaces70.ftress.aspace.com
 
var keyToMask =p('mask.key') splitBy ','
 
fun mask(val)="******"
 
fun needsMasking(key)=(sizeOf (keyToMask find key)) > 0
 
fun maskSensitiveData(value)=value mapObject ({
($$) : maskSensitiveData($) when $ is Object otherwise $
} unless needsMasking($$ as :string) otherwise {
  ($$) : mask($)
})
 
---
 
maskSensitiveData(vars.originalPayload)]]>
```

Comment: What is the logic that the script is implementing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should understand DataWeave 2, not try to translate blindly.

I replaced the condition by pattern matching and if. It make the intention much more clear. Also the contains() function is much clear and simple to use for verifying that the key should be masked and returns a boolean directly.

Example:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/xml encoding = 'utf-8'
 
var keysToMask ="abc,def" splitBy ',' // replace with the actual source of the keys
 
fun mask(val)="******"
 
fun maskSensitiveData(value)=
    value match {
        case obj is Object -> value mapObject {
            ($$) : if (keysToMask contains ($$ as String)) mask($)
                   else maskSensitiveData($)
        }
        else -> value 
    }
---
maskSensitiveData(payload)
```

Input:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root>
  <xyz>123</xyz>
  <abc>456</abc>
</root>
```

Output:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root>
  <xyz>123</xyz>
  <abc>******</abc>
</root>
```

Comment: Actually, I am new to both dataweave 1.2 and 2.0 , so could not understand lot of syntax used there, Also in your solution, I dont see the function "needsMasking" called anywhere which was there in the dw1.2 snippet under "unless", do we have a replacement for unless in dw 2.0 just like we have for when and otherwise.

Comment: I just checked "contains" does not work with this use case, only when i replace it with "find" it is able to validate correct keyToMask.

Comment: Right, I forgot to remove needsMasking(). If it doesn't work then you probably did not enough reproduction information for me to validate it.

Comment: @NaveenPoddar what do you mean by contains() doesn't work? I added my example input and actual output that I used to test the script and seem to work correctly.

Comment: @Adel I was testing the code using the method "needsMasking" where you substituted 'find' with 'contains' at first, but now I realized why you did not call the method as it also contains sizeof method which why it did not work.  Apologies for the confusion and thank you so much for providing the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Slight change to Adel's solution. I added the call to function needsMasking

```html
%dw 2.0
output application/xml encoding = 'utf-8'
 
var keysToMask ="abc,def" splitBy ',' // replace with the actual source of the keys
 
fun mask(val)="******"
 
fun needsMasking(key)=(sizeOf (keysToMask find key)) > 0
 
fun maskSensitiveData(value)=
    value match {
        case obj is Object -> value mapObject {
            ($$) : if (needsMasking ($$ as String)) mask($)
                   else maskSensitiveData($)
        }
        else -> value 
    }
---
maskSensitiveData(payload)
```